# How to get average of list within lists using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, average

I am creating a method that will get a list of business objects that tie for the highest average rating. The method starts with a list of businesses. Each business contains a list of review objects that contain a rating (int).

To illustrate:

```
list<Review> reviews = curtBusiness.getReviews();
reviews[1].GetRating();
```

Using a for loop I could find this easily, unfortunately however I am required to use linq, something I have almost no skills at.

Can anyone help me make a linq statement for this query or for a similar query?

**Update:**

I think I may have stumbled into a solution

```
 double average = busInCat.Max(b=> b.GetReviews().Average(r => r.getRateing()));
        return busInCat.Where(b => b.GetReviews().Average(r => r.getRateing()) == average).ToList();
```

If the above code is correct then it first finds the max average of ratings in the first line.

Then in the second line returns a list of of the businesses that have that average rating. Can anyone confirm this is what the linq expressions is doing?

Comment: small nit-pick: `getRateing` should probably be spelled `getRating`, and since it's a method it should be PascalCase: `GetRating`...

Comment: no worries my spelling is deplorable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the solution I put in the update:

```
double average = busInCat.Max(b=> b.GetReviews().Average(r => r.getRateing()));
return busInCat.Where(b => b.GetReviews().Average(r => r.getRateing()) == average).T
```

The above code does indeed work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you're looking for here, but I'll take a guess.

You have a `Review` object, that has a method like `int getRating()`, you have a list of these objects and you want to find the average of the ratings

Something like this would do the trick

```
// get your reviews
var reviews = curtBusiness.getReviews();

// get the average of the getRating() results of the reviews
var average = reviews.Average(r => r.getRating());
```

Is this what you're looking for?  I can offer further explanation, but I'd like to be sure this is what you're after.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness. I have updated the question with what i think is a solution. If it is then it should shed some light on what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to do this in one statement:

```
busInCat.Select(b => new { b, Avg = b.GetReviews().Average(r => r.GetRating()) })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Avg, x => x.b)
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

This first build a list of businesses and their averages. Then it groups by the averages, sorts the groups in descending order of their keys (the average) and takes the first group. This group is an `IEnumerable<Business>`, i.e. the businesses that tie for the highest average.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LINQ statement to extract the list of ratings, then call the [`Average`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354760.aspx) function on that list:

```
var average = (
    from r in reviews
    select r.getRateing()
    ).Average();
```